# Load single value from multiple value image field in View

Tags: views, entities

I am trying to load a single value from a multiple value image field in View.
I am adding the field with a restriction to print only a single file. I am also filtering by delta(=0). Check the settings in the attachment.

However the view is loading all images attached to the field. How can I load only the 1st one?

[image]

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: Try to delete the delta field. You only need the content field and the restriction on the display values (like you did on the screenshot)

Comment: @robin that was my initial approach which did not work.

Comment: @Robin this solved it, please make it an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: Potney Switters, posted it as an asnwer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete the delta field. You only need the content field and the restriction on the display values (like you did on the screenshot).

Answer (score -2):

I think should be using agregation and unique option at query options inside advanced tab

Comment: Aggregation is used when you want to group multiple rows. This example is multiple values in one row